# What are various specifications of Engine oil used in Piston and Turbine engine aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance, aircraft-maintenance

I only know of two types MIL-O-7808 and -23699. Is there anything else ?

Comment: Some evidence of research could improve this question, but it's similar to existing questions like: [What are the differences between fuel types (comparing with vehicles)?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12184/1696)

Comment: Depending on what you have in mind, a full answer to this could run to hundreds of different products used over a period of several decades. Please try to narrow the scope.

Comment: @pritam the oil specifications are on the Jet Aircraft Engine Lubrication System link in my answer below. Just click on it and scroll down to the list of lubricant types there are about a dozen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a general answer for a general question.

Function of oil is three-fold for both piston and turbine engines:

1. Lubrication - reduction of friction;
2. Cooling - carrying away of heat; and
3. Cleaning - carrying away of contamination.

Oils used in jet engines must be able to withstand temperatures that are much hotter than piston engines.

Here is a link to some of the lubricating oils used in navy jet aircraft and the various specifications.

[Jet Aircraft Engine Lubrication Systems](http://navybmr.com/study%20material/14008a/14008A_ch5.pdf)

Piston aircraft engines tend to be air-cooled and are therefore manufactured with larger tolerances. This results in an engine that uses up oil (burns it). Most POH of piston aircraft that I've seen call for ashless dispersant oil, which refers to an oil that has non-metallic additives and has the ability to suspend combustion particles.

Here is an article that describes [piston aviation oils](http://www.swaviator.com/html/issueja02/Hangar7802.html).